Qiskit: Density matrix's dimension is too large
My circuit is with 18 qubits. I want to find density matrix by calling DensityMatrix.from_instruction(qc) but then I get an error "Maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 36". Any suggestions on a workaround? Is there a way to specify the output to be np.array rather than np.ndarray?

Can you please provide your code? In particular, does your code include mid-circuit measurements?
